# Vue.js: Why won't my data display in this list containing multiple component types?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get to a point where I can have multiple component types being rendered within a single parent. It's not something which is easy to search for answers on.

I know that it is differentiating the components by adding something to the templates to distinguish them, but if I pass data as you'll see below, I get nothing, any tips?

Edit: I also don't want to have to render out these components in the HTML for this to work, needs to be passed in via JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <component v-for="widget in widgets" :is="widget.type"></component>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    Vue.config.debug = true

    Vue.component('component-a', {
        template: '<p>{{foo}}</p>',
        props: ['foo',]
    });

    Vue.component('component-b', {
        template: '<p>{{bar}}</p>',
        props: ['bar',]
    });

    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            widgets: [
                {
                    type: "component-a",
                    foo: 'Hello'
                },
                {
                    type: "component-b",
                    bar: "World",
                },
            ]
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're not passing any props for the `foo` and `bar` elements

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <component v-for="widget in widgets" :is="widget.type" :foo="widget.foo" :bar="widget.bar"></component>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    Vue.config.debug = true

    Vue.component('component-a', {
        template: '<p>{{foo}}</p>',
        props: ['foo',]
    });

    Vue.component('component-b', {
        template: '<p>{{bar}}</p>',
        props: ['bar',]
    });

    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            widgets: [
                {
                    type: "component-a",
                    foo: 'Hello'
                },
                {
                    type: "component-b",
                    bar: "World",
                },
            ]
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qj1ufnet/)

In your example the components are rendering with empty strings so you're not seeing the values you're trying to pass. when using interchangeable components it's often best to use a common value interface. Something along the lines of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <component v-for="widget in widgets" :is="widget.type" :value="widget.value"></component>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    Vue.config.debug = true

    Vue.component('component-a', {
        template: '<p>{{value.foo}}</p>',
        props: ['value',]
    });

    Vue.component('component-b', {
        template: '<p>{{value.bar}}</p>',
        props: ['value',]
    });

    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            widgets: [
                {
                    type: "component-a",
                    value: {
                        foo: 'Hello'
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: "component-b",
                    value: {
                        bar: "World",
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So that the components only pass the single value object to the component necessary and the component pulls the unique values from that object.

Comment: @JamesN No problem. Glad I could help and good luck with your project.